# Cant fetch the data php back end with my login angular project

Tags: php, json, angular

I'm trying to make an angular project but when I tried to fetch data from a php file it wont let me and there's an error such as

"Property 'success' does not exist on type 'Object'." on if(data.success){
"Property 'message' does not exist on type 'Object'." on window.alert(data.message)

here is the code

This is my loginComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private Auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  loginUser(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    const target = event.target
    const username = target.querySelector('#username').value
    const password = target.querySelector('#password').value

    this.Auth.getUserDetails(username, password).subscribe(data => {
      if(data.success){ //this part is the error
      } else {
        window.alert(data.message) //this part too
      }
    })
  }

}
```

this is My AuthService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUserDetails(username, password){

    return this.http.post('/api/auth.php', {
      username,
      password
    })

  }

}
```

this is my php file auth.php:

```
<?php

  $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

  if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if($username == 'admin' && $password == 'admin'){
      ?>
    {
      "success": true,
      "secret": "This is the secret no one knows but the admin"
    }
      <?php
    } else {
      ?>
    {
      "success": false,
      "secret": "Invalid credentials"
    }

    <?php
    }
  } else {
    ?>
    {
      "success": false,
      "message": "Only POST access accepted"
    }

    <?php
  }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this in *loginComponent*:

```
this.Auth.getUserDetails(username, password).subscribe(data => {
  if (data && data['success']) { 
  } else {
    window.alert(data['message']) 
  }
})
```